# Read download a file using a link from an external csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to take a link from a csv file, download it, and change the filename, again using data from the csv file. Running the code below results in this error:

```
~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in get_adapter(self, url)
    740 
    741         # Nothing matches :-/
--> 742         raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for {!r}".format(url))
    743 
    744     def close(self):

InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for "('Links', 0       https://eccdcf94738f34d487f9-0cee2c305dfdc401c...\n1       https://eccdcf94738f34d487f9-0cee2c305dfdc401c...\n2       https://eccdcf94738f34d487f9-0cee2c305dfdc401c...\n3       https://eccdcf94738f34d487f9-0cee2c305dfdc401c...\n4       https://eccdcf94738f34d487f9-0cee2c305dfdc401c...\n                              ...                        \n2790    https://eccdcf94738f34d487f9-0cee2c305dfdc401c...\n2791    https://eccdcf94738f34d487f9-0cee2c305dfdc401c...\n2792    https://eccdcf94738f34d487f9-0cee2c305dfdc401c...\n2793    https://eccdcf94738f34d487f9-0cee2c305dfdc401c...\n2794    https://eccdcf94738f34d487f9-0cee2c305dfdc401c...\nName: Links, Length: 2795, dtype: object)"
```

I have tried removing the header, and passing `header = None` through read_csv, but I then can't specify the column to read from. Anyone have any ideas on how to remedy this?

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse




firstNames = pandas.read_csv('e://DELETEAFTERUSE/PwC_links.csv', usecols=['FirstName'])
lastNames = pandas.read_csv('e://DELETEAFTERUSE/PwC_links.csv', usecols=['LastName'])
links = lastNames = pandas.read_csv('e://DELETEAFTERUSE/PwC_links.csv', usecols=['Links'])


def run():
    for item in firstNames.iteritems():
        firstname = item
        for item in lastNames.iteritems():
            lastname = item
            for item in links.iteritems():
                ftd = requests.get(item)
                split = urlparse.urlsplit(item)
                filename = "e:/DELETEAFTERUSE/" + firstname + lastname + split.path.split("/")[-1]
                open(filename, 'wb').write(ftd.content)

        
run()
```

Comment: its a bit hard to tell without your actuall data. but it looks like your links arent links.

Comment: i have tested the links, and they do work. The error message just shortened them down.

Comment: You are not splitting the links. its trying to get all the rows of links as one link.
"('Links', 0       https://eccdcf94738f34d487f9-0cee2c305dfdc401c...\n1       https://eccdcf94738f34d487f9-0cee2c305dfdc401c...\n2       https://eccdcf94738f34d487f9-0cee2c305dfdc401c...\n3" this is not a url

Comment: why do you read CSV three times ? Why not read once. And check `print(links)` because it seems you have all data in one string - maybe you incorrectly created this file OR maybe it need extra options to read it correctly. Mabye it need spaces as separator `read_csv(..., sep="\s+")` - normally CSV uses `,` to separate columns